# Link to my LibraryThing page instead of entering books I've read manually

Tags: feature-request, jobs

I am currently filling out my Careers 2.0 profile. Instead of entering the programming books I've read manually, I think it would be great if I could just link to my [LibraryThing](http://librarything.com) page (or a similar service if there are other, more popular ones) where I have already cataloged everything I've read, similar to how I can link to my code repositories at GitHub. Maybe one could limit this to just one tag that I would flag every book I want to share on my profile with.

Comment: +1, but are you sure you want every old and crusty tech book you've ever read showing up?  Not that it would hurt you, I'd just think you'd want to manually separate the wheat from the chaff